# How to define minimal length of character to fire jQuery Mobile listview search

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I've got a very huge  (over 1000 records) listview, every time I type in search field will fire listview filter process and it is very slow especially when first character typed. However is any quick way to define minimal length to fire filter process in jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own search `filterCallback` function with something maybe like this:

```
yourFilterFunction = function( text, searchValue ){
  if (searchValue.length < 3) // automatically omit search terms less than 3
  {
    return 0;
  }
  return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
};

$("#mylist").listview('option', 'filterCallback', yourFilterFunction);
```

The `filterCallback` function returns **0** when the search term is less than 3.  This should prevent it from iterating over your entire collection of list items.

If this doesn't do it for you, I suggest rolling your own (ajax enabled?) search filter.

Documentation here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although this gives the appearance of what's wanted, it will still iterate over the entire collection.  Line 5810: .bind( "keyup change", function() {...  the code that calls the filterCallback is executed on keyup or change.  Also, the callback itself is contained within the for loop that iterates all of the LI items.